# How To Add "Username" Under Logo After Login

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m trying to add a “Username” under the image logo of my webpage after User login.
I want to add Session variable here to capture the username and after that want to call the “Session” value in the html code under the logo of my webpage.

My C# file code (Main.cs) file name
:

```
[ModuleMethodAttribute(Require_Post = true)]
public string Auth(string Username, string Password, string CompanyRpt)
{
    AuthenticationRequest Login = new AuthenticationRequest();

    Login.Username = Username;
    Login.Password = Password;

    //Login.Username = "dev1";
    //Login.Password = "password";

    AuthenticationResult Result = Login.Execute();

    if (Result.Authenticated)
    {
        Result.Commit();
        Instance.Session.Add("CompanyRpt", CompanyRpt);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/index.html");
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return "login failure - " + Result.Message;
    }
}
```

My Navigation HTML file code:

```
<nav class="sidenav left hidden-print" role="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="user">
        <div class="content">
            Logo will appear here
        </div>
```

The username should appear under the image that has been called here.

Comment: By "username", do you mean the value they logged in with (i.e. jake@state.farm), or a "friendly name", like "Jake from State Farm"?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, It's the name that they login with

Comment: Is this actually ASP.NET MVC, because this looks more like WebForms code. If it's MVC, which view engine are you using (in other words, are you using `<%: %>` or `@`)?

Comment: pardon me for my ignorance, but I'm newbie to coding. How can I figure out which one I'm using. If this helps.. We use bootstrap frame work here

Comment: MVC has, well, **m**odels, **v**iews, and **c**ontrollers. If you're using WebForms you have something like, say, a Default.aspx combined with a Default.aspx.cs code-behind file. As for which view engine if you're using MVC, I explained that in a previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net mvc you can simply do this:

```
<div class="content">
  Logo will appear here
  @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    <span class="logo">@User.Identity.Name</span>
  }
</div>
```

**EDIT:** as it turns out from the comments, OP is not using ASP.NET (despite having asp.net tags in his/her question at the time of me answering), thus this answer is invalid.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.the application did not allow me to post the actual code referring to image.Here is the actual code of html file. <style>
  .sidenav ul.dropdown-menu {
   top: 200px;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
  }
 </style>
 <nav class="sidenav left hidden-print" role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
 <li class="user">
 <div class="content">
 <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" width="254" height="120" alt="logo" />
     </div>

     <div class="content">
   @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    <span class="logo">@User.Identity.Name</span>
  }
</div>

Comment: When I reun this, this is what is displayed under the logo of my page "@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { @User.Identity.Name }"

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC with Razor engine or classic ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: pardon me for my ignorance, but I'm newbie to coding. How can I figure out which one I'm using. If this helps.. We use bootstrap frame work here

Comment: Don't worry about it, there is no person on Earth who knows everything :)
Razor template files have the extension .cshtml like so: MyView.cshtml while classic asp.net webforms template files look like this: MyView.aspx

Comment: @ngergo6 Worth noting that MVC projects can use the `.aspx` extension for views as well, if they're using the WebForms view engine (Razor was introduced in MVC3, if I recall correctly).

Comment: Thnx for the information. The files that I’m using 
1. Main.cs 
This is where I have the “Auth” function 
2. Nav.html
This is where my webpage design is coded. Calling logo is from here.
3. Default.cs
This file is referring to the Nav.html. I’ve added below code
 public string Nav()    {
        if (IsAuthenticated)
{
var nav = ModuleTemplate("Modules/Default/Nav.html");
tmc.Add("Path", Instance.Page.Path);
tmc.Add("UserName", Authentication.Contact_First + " " + Authentication.Contact_Last);
 return nav.ToString();
 }

Comment: Hi I just confirmed that we are not using any views in this project. For UI responses, we use JS. Server Side : C# with SQL and for front end - bootstrap that uses HTML,CSS and Javascripts

Comment: @aruna: so you are using asp.net web api?

Comment: @TiesonT.: thanks for correcting me, you are right, I was making assumptions

Comment: @ngergo6 : As I mentioned no asp

Comment: Then i'm sorry but i'm afraid i can't help you. You will have to consult the manual or documentation of the web/authentication framework you are using or alternatively you can create a server side method that returns the logged in user for the current session.

Comment: Also could you please remove the asp.net tags from your question? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is ASP.Net form use protected variable in code behind and use it in html inside <%= %>.

Ex:

// in C# inside your

```
 protected string _UserName = String.Empty;

 ...

public string Auth(string Username, string Password, string CompanyRpt)
{
  --- 
  _UserName  = "nam---";
 }
```

In Html

```
   <div class="content">
        Logo will appear here
     <%=_UserName  %>
    </div>
```

Comment: public string Auth(string Username, string Password, string CompanyRpt)
    {
        AuthenticationRequest Login = new AuthenticationRequest();

        Login.Username = Username;
        Login.Password = Password;


        AuthenticationResult Result = Login.Execute();

        if (Result.Authenticated)
        {
            Result.Commit();
            Instance.Session.Add("CompanyRpt", CompanyRpt);

   _UserName  = "Username";

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking time out to help me. When I have added _UserName= "Username" in the .cs file I'm getting a compiler error with message "CS0103: The name '_UserName' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Did you make it as "Protected". or try to use it as "Public". make sure this is Asp.net web Form not in MVC and also if it is master page this needs to go in to master page .cs file

Answer (score 0):

Thank U all for trying to help me.

Have figured out the solution for my case.

I had to "tmc.Add("UserName", Authentication.Contact_First + " " + Authentication.Contact_Last);" to my default.cs file that was invoking the Navigation HTML file.

Then in the Navigation HTML file I had to add this under the code that calls the logo 
 Welcome:  **{UserName}**

That is it! Now I'm all set to see my name after login!